# Creating a regex redirect based on domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I run a Wordpress Multisite that uses domain mapping. All domains point to the same Wordpress installation on, let's say, `admin.com`. They share the same .htaccess file.

However, with my basic .htaccess knowledge, I can't manage to make up a redirect that results in the following:

```
site1.com/admin > site1.admin.com/app
site2.net/admin > site2.admin.com/app
site3.fr/admin > site3.admin.com/app
```

And so on.

Can this be done using regex in a redirect? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If your "basic .htaccess knowledge" is not enough you should start reading the documentation of the tools you use. Start here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly this is possible. And actually it is not exactly complex, you can implement one rule per case:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?admin$ https://site1.admin.com/app [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?admin$ https://site2.admin.com/app [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site3\.fr$
RewriteRule ^/?admin https://site3.admin.com/app [R=301]
```

This rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and in case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

I do not see a way to implement a single rule handling all cases, since there is no mapping function defined for that. Most likely you will need to adapt the site names to your real cases (doubt you actually use the domain `admin.com`...), but above rules should give you the basic direction from where you can work.

There is nothing complex here, all of this is documented and shown with easy and realistic examples in the apache documentation. You really should start looking into that if you have questions about rewriting.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. The RewriteRules you are suggesting are not very complex indeed, my 'basic knowledge' was enough to come up with these ;)

However, the point of my question was if there was a possibility to have one single rule 'to rule them all', but since you point out there is no way to implement that, my question is still answered.